# how to filter a column in datagridview imported from excel file

Tags: c#, .net, filter

For example I have a datagridview1 with data imported from a excel file and there are 12 columns: date, Name, Activity, Project,time, comment,ect. and 1000 row.
What I want to do is to filter only all with the Project name in project column.
for example I have support as a (Projectname) I want to show all columns filtyring by support rows.

I have combobox to select which column I need to filter it( e.g Project) here,
I tried with this code but it dose not work.

```
  private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string projektItem = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    if (projektItem == "Project") {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                filter.Append(dataRow[i].ToString());
                filter.Append("\t");
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = filter.ToString();
        }

    if (projektItem == "Name") {
    }
    if (projektItem == "Aktivity") {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it. convert datagridview to datatable

And this is func for filter purpose:
Hold the origin table to go back if you turn your filter off

```
//datagrid to datatable
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
datatable = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource; 

//datatableOrigin to hold your origin table
DataTable originTable = null;

// find Function
Public void Find(string column, string st)
{
    DataRow[] dtResult;
    DataTable holder = New DataTable;

    //get datatable Schema
    DataTable holder = datatable.Clone();
    holder.Rows.Clear();

    If (originTable != null)
        datatable = originTable;
    Else
        originTable = datatable;

    //select return datarow array
    dtResult = datatable.Select("[" + column + "] LIKE '%" + st + "%'");

    //import all your result into holder
    foreach(DataRow dr In dtResult){holder.ImportRow(dr);}

    //pass from holder to datatable
    datatable = holder.Copy();
    holder.Clear();
}

public void showDT()
{
      dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // choose your column here

}

private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Find('YourColumn, 'your search string);
    showDT();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer but it dose not work, What is dtResult,   originTable, datatable, st . Where I but the first rows  DataTable dtFromGrid = new DataTable();
dtFromGrid = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

Comment: The upper part is how you convert your datagridview to datatable

Comment: originTable is where you hold your origin table to go back if you turn your filter off

Comment: i edited it a litte bit already, i convert my code from vb.net to C# so there might be some systax problem, but thats the way to go!

Comment: At Find we have two patametrs what should be (string column, string...…….)
 in the second one

Comment: oops, your right, i miss typed it, its the string what you put in the datatable select

Comment: you mean "st" here, what is dtResult here .

Comment: just the what hold your result, datatable.select return datarow array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202554/discussion-between-mariowu-and-osama).